# express upload file with multer not working with urlencodedParser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post, multer

I am trying to upload an image with a post request form. In my express.js server I am both using multer and urlencodedParser, because I am passing all the html inputs as a json object through the post request body plus a selection of a file, which I am handeling it with multer.

Here is the HTML code for the form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/api/addOrgs" method="post">
    <div class="form-row">
        <!-- OTHER CODE -->
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Image or Logo</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="fileToUpload">
            </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">  Add the organization to the system</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have set up the multer:

```
// add image to folder
var multer  = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '../public/images/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Here is the express post request handler:

```
// to add a new organization to the list
app.post('/api/addOrgs', upload.single('imageToUpload'), urlencodedParser, (req, res)=> {
    try {
        var newobj = req.body;

        // want to change name of id in obj
        // add image name and delete image field
        newobj['img'] = newobj.image;
        delete newobj.image;

        // read orgs file
        let orgs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../orgs.json')));
        
        //... OTHER CODE
        // send respond
        res.send('<h1>Successfully added!</h1><br><p>'+JSON.stringify(newobj, null, 4)+'</p></br><b>Now you can go <a href="/good">BACK</a></b>')
       // OTHER CODE
    } catch (e) {
        // ... OTHER CODE
    }
});
```

The problem is that I successfully have the name of the file uploaded in the json object sent through the req.body but **it does NOT save the file in the folder**. Is the problem coming from the usage of `urlencodedParser` for the `app.post()` parameter?

Or do I have to do something in order to save the file inside my `app.post()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file's form should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute. Try this, and it should work

Comment: So I had to modify the html form like you said `<form action="http://localhost:8000/api/addOrgs" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` then also had an issue of naming in the function `upload.single('imageToUpload')` and had to be rewrite as `upload.single('image')` since the input tag has `name="image"`.

Comment: Yes, that's also a must.. Anyway, glad to hear you're code is up and running again!